# Why do I get random white space in header_arg expansions when running shell scripts from Babel?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Please consider the following org-mode snippet containing code to call "show tables" on  a particular database via a sql code block and to dump out the database via mysqldump using an sh code block

```
*** Database
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :engine "mysql" :dbuser "user" :dbpassword "password" :dbhost "127.0.0.1" :database "mydb" :var dbuser="user" :var dbpassword="password" :var dbhost="127.0.0.1" :var database="mydb"
:END:

**** Test connectivity
#+begin_src sql
show tables;
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:

**** Dump schema
#+begin_src sh 
echo mysqldump -u $dbuser -p $dbpassword -h $dbhost $database
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: mysqldump -u user^M^M -p password^M^M -h 127.0.0.1^M^M mydb
```

You will note that the line that is echoed contains spurious whitespace (line ends by the look of it).

**Why is this and how can I make it go away?**

If I remove the echo from the sh code block then I get the following error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 2005: "Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1^M^M' (8)" when trying to connect
```

So the whitespace is really there.  I am running GNU Emacs 25.0.94.2 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2016-05-26 on Windows 10.  So it might be a Windows problem - haven't tried it on Linux yet, will do that when I get home from work.

**For bonus marks, can someone tell me how to refactor the header_args so that I don't have to declare everything twice (once for SQL language specific headers and once for code block variables)?**

Let me know what additional information I should provide as this is my first post.

Comment: The problem isn't there on emacs 24.5.1 on linux.

Comment: Thanks for checking.  This is happening for me on every header-arg referenced from an sh code block - it's making it difficult to use code blocks effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after much banging my head on this, I think I've worked it out.  The spurious ^M characters are not as such caused by Emacs specifically but by any Windows program interacting with the Cygwin bash shell (which I am using).

Putting the following into ~/.emacs will tell bash to ignore spurious carriage returns and all my problems go away:

```
(setenv "SHELLOPTS" "igncr")
```